# Help differentiating passive from potential form

Tags: meaning

In this sentence:

> おもしろさなどが、時間の経過とともにじわじわと**感じられる**という意味です。

Is  感じられる in the potential form or in the passive form? The context is the word じわじわ being defined. The whole paragraph is:

> 「じわる」は、副詞の「じわじわ」に動詞の辞書形「る」をつけて、グループ１の動詞になります。 おもしろさなどが、時間の経過とともにじわじわと**感じられる**という意味です。

Comment: 自発(spontaneous)の「れる・られる」だと思いますが。。http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42680/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer:

It is neither potential nor passive voice.  It is, as @Shoko points out in the comment above, used to indicate **spontaneous** occurrence.

So, that dictionary definition in question is along the lines of:

> "One (spontaneously) feels the appeal (and such) more and more as time passes."

### Long Answer:

Learn the **four** functions of 「れる・られる」 today if you have not done so because it is very important and useful.  Quite frankly, there is no such thing as fluent Japanese without being able to use all four of them both actively and correctly.

**1) Passive Voice**:

> 「犬{いぬ}に噛{か}ま**れる**。」 "(Someone) is bitten by a dog."
>
> 「よく女性{じょせい}に声{こえ}をかけ**られる**。」 "(I) am often approached by women."

**2) Potential**:

> 「来｛こ｝**られる**人｛ひと｝は来｛き｝てください。」 "Those who can come, please come."
>
> 「[4L]{よんエル}でないと着{き}**られない**。」 "I could not wear it unless it is in size 4L."

**3) Respect**:

> 「エリザベス女王{じょおう}が来日{らいにち}さ**れる**。」 "Queen Elizabeth visits Japan."
>
> 「先生{せんせい}が来{こ}**られる**。」 "The teacher comes/is coming."

**4) Spontaneous**:

> 「故郷{ふるさと}のことが思{おも}い出{だ}さ**れる**。」 "I am missing my hometown."
>
> 「このピッチャーには将来性{しょうらいせい}が感{かん}じ**られる**。」 "I can see/feel a bright future for this pitcher."

Comment: so, is が marking the subject(おもしろさなど) here? or does it mean "and"

Comment: It is marking the subject.   Once the sentence is "translated" into another language, however, that can get hard to see, which is often the source of misunderstanding observed here on SE.  People here tend to look at the translation harder than the original in telling what the subject or object is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is passive, referring to how 「おもしろさ」*is felt*.

> おもしろさなど**が**、時間の経過とともにじわじわと**感じられる**