# Can「される」mean「させられる」?

Tags: passive-voice, causation

Recently, I looked up「気が引ける」in 旺文社国語辞典

> きがひける【気が引ける】
>
> うしろめたい感じがして気おくれする。**遠慮される**。

It's odd to me that「遠慮する」is written in passive. I thought it was a typo at first then it occurred to me this「される」can be understood as「させられる」. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This される does not have the passive meaning. It's a less common usage of (ら)れる known as 自発 ("spontaneous").

- [Why is the passive form used in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42680/5010)
- [Is there a reason why the passive and the potential form are identical (at least for える/いる verbs)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60050/5010)

So this 遠慮される means something along the lines of なんとなく遠慮したい気持ちになる ("to spontaneously feel like refraining"). 遠慮させられる is different because it means some external pressure is making you to do 遠慮.