# Passive referring to one's own actions

Tags: passive-voice

for example

> 優美な笑顔を**向けられ**、そう答えるしかなかった。
>
> 寝たきりだった体を起こした時のような鈍い痛みが全身に走っていて、それは彼女と森で出会った頃よりも強く**感じられた**。

In these cases, the first person narrator is describing his own actions.

In what circumstances would you choose to use the passive form for your actions?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 優美な笑顔を向けられ、そう答えるしかなかった。

The subject of 優美な笑顔を向け**られる** and そう答える is the same person, so the 向けられる is normal passive.

> "I **was given** an elegant smile, so I had no choice but reply that way."

優美な笑顔を向け**る**, "to give an elegant smile", was done by someone else.

---

> 寝たきりだった体を起こした時のような鈍い痛みが全身に走っていて、それは彼女と森で出会った頃よりも強く感じられた。

The 感じ**られる** is spontaneous (自発), not passive (受け身).

For more on the usage of the spontaneous auxiliary れる・られる, you could refer to [Why is the passive form used in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42680/9831)